# Magento Marketplace extension

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.4

I have installed my extension marketplace in magento. When I install it the product description page does not displace as before. Pls can any1 suggest what can i do. 
The main path for the description page is app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtm

But when the extension is installed it goes into 
frontend/base/default/template/marketplace/catalog/product/view.phtm

I want to get it to app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtm.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Switch on hints to get block class and .phtml.

Here you will get idea of parent block for this child block and so you will also get to know phtml associated to parent block.In this .phtml there will be a call to block child you need to map this block to your product.view.phtml

other way is to remove this marketplace view.phtml from source code as a fall back system Magento will take default view.phtml file

Comment: The 2nd option does not work. Pls suggest the 1st option  how can i go about...  I have enabled my hints .. I get the marketplace cald just at 1 block

Comment: set hints on. then check .phtml and block class and paste those here.

Comment: These are the hints frontend/base/default/template/em_cms/widget/static_block/default.phtml     frontend/base/default/template/marketplace/catalog/product/view.phtml need dis one to be direct template/catalog/product/view.phtml                                    which blocks code do I put here ?

Comment: you have not stated block name.Need to check parent block and check what child html is being called

Comment: paste screen shot after setting block and template hint on.

Comment: I cant add an image hrer... can i get an email id to mail it?